# Angular CLI Node.js compatibility issue: Angular CLI requires minimum Node.js version 18, but Angular 12 project doesn't support this Node.js version

Tags: node.js, angular, nvm, angular12

I'm diving into Angular as a beginner and currently working on a project specifically with Angular 12. To set things up, I opted not to install Angular CLI globally and instead used `npx -p @angular/cli@12 new hello-world-project`. Following Angular's documentation, I noted that the required Node.js version should be **^12.14.0 || ^14.15.0**. So, with the help of nvm, I switched to the specified Node version mentioned in the documentation.

However, upon trying to run the application with `ng serve`, I encountered an issue stating that **The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.**. It's quite puzzling because even when I adjust the Node version to the minimum required, say 18.13, the Angular CLI functions, but my application fails to run, throwing a compatibility error related to Node:

> Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
> Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...node:internal/crypto/hash:69
> this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
> ^
>
> Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

[image]

Do any of you have an idea if I've missed something? Just to note, I'm working on Windows.

I've already attempted to switch my Node version to 12.14 and 14.5, as well as some versions below those, but to no avail. Interestingly, whenever I opt for a version higher than 18.13, my application throws an error indicating incompatibility with Node.

Comment: If you didn't completely reinstalled project deps when switching to a new node version, you should have done that

Answer (score 0):

You are using Angular 12.2.x and you must following supported NODE.JS [version](https://angular.io/guide/versions)

**Version compatibility: NG 12.2.x **

```
^12.14.0 || ^14.15.0
```

If you are using nvm, make sure that the required version is correctly installed on local.

**Exemple**

```
nvm install 12.14.0

node -v
```

If you want to see what versions are installed :

```
nvm ls
```

So remove your **node_modules**, clean your cache with ***npm cache clean —-force,*** and retry to install dependencies with ***npm install***.

Comment: Hey there! I've tried clearing the cache, deleted the node_modules, and performed another npm install, but it's still not cooperating. Plus, I've made sure not to have Angular CLI installed globally to avoid any potential errors. Instead, I installed Angular CLI and the project within a specific folder. Also, I'm using nvm, and it's already set to version 12.14. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @LarissaRodrigues what potential errors are you predicting? Sounds like you're running into an actual error by not installing it as suggested

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve my issue! I reinstalled the Angular CLI globally to version 12, ensured Node was on version 12.14.1, and reinstalled the project. Now it's running smoothly with ng serve.